# Install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 10 (Manta) Using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, flash

fastboot oem unlock results in the tablet displaying the green Android robot lying and message saying the device is already unlocked. My presumption is that Android OS is no longer in the tablet.

`ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap` results in the following:

- Ubuntu icon with various options allowed is displayed.  I wait for the command to finish.
- The command finishes with "Rebooting into recovery to flash" and at about the same time a spinning Ubuntu icon appears.  My assumption here is that flashing is occurring.
- after a bit of time the 4 flashing colors appear.  My assumption here is that the flash has failed.

I can boot the tablet into recovery which allows me to access the various options as in a) above.  Both `/factory` and `/cache` are mounted.  Should they be?  Install zip sounds interesting and wipe data/factory reset sounds interesting.  I am leery of doing these without advisement.

Suggestions?  Should I do the reload android os procedure from the backup I made and start again?

Answer (score 0):

On a Nexus 10, you can use the Ubuntu Dualboot app to install it and keep Android in case something goes wrong. Hope that helped!

Comment: nexus 10 - manta